# C++ DX10 program exception 0xc0000005

Tags: c++, exception, directx

I tried to run Raster Tek's DX10 tutorial, found here: http://www.rastertek.com/dx10tut03.html

Everytime it crashed with the 0xc0000005 exception at the line:

```
m_device->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_renderTargetView, m_depthStencilView);
```

I tried to rearrange the code, to have no releases before this line, i modified to have m_depthStencilView as NULL, later m_renderTargetView as NULL also, but the function OMSetRenderTargets fails everytime with the very same exception, violating memory.

I'm using VC2012 with DirectX SDK, but also tried to run it under VC2010, with the same result.

I don't have any clue now, what the issue really is, can somebody please take a look at this?

Comment: Have you made sure the `m_device` is a valid pointer?

Comment: Please add the declaration of `OMSetRenderTargets()`.

Comment: m_Device is valid, for as you can see in the full code on the link above, it is used to make the render target view, and I could find no problem with that, and even in the debugger watch m_Device has non-zero value.
OMSetRenderTargets is a member of ID3D11DeviceContext, please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I downloaded the code, upgraded it to VS2012 and it compiles and runs fine. Unless you changed any code, it may be that your graphics hardware doesn't support some features.

Comment: Thanks Roger. I got a GTX-570, so my guess is that it may not be a hardware, but a DirectX issue. I'll try to reinstall the SDK, to see what happens.

Comment: Sure it was hardware error, tried DX11 sample, which worked fine. So I have to switch to DX11. Or back to 9. :-)